# a computer issue that has stumped many - iTunes/VLC/any audio starts skipping after several hours

Tags: windows-7, audio, desktop

I gave an old desktop to a buddy of mine. It was in use as a fileserver/media server in my apartment, and I finally did some upgrades, yada yada. It was perfectly fine here.

Problem description: Since moving it to my buddy's place out in the sticks, it's been unable to play media consistently. It stutters horrifically using iTunes and VLC to play music, like a CD with a horrific scratch in it. This thing was streaming music and 720p video without trouble back home. Needless to say, I'm confused.

Attempted fixes: So far, we've done a full RAM integrity test, ran chkdsk against the harddrive for bad sectors, done a complete scan via malwarebytes, jrt, adw and combofixed it to no success. Reinstalled the sound driver, even disabled search indexing as it does have an external USB 2.0 HD hooked up to it. It was a clean windows 7 pro install when I left it with him 3 weeks ago, all up to date. Crystal Disk and Real Temp have been used, Crystal Disk came back with nothing wrong, Real Temp came back with 37 degrees under major stress, 3 flash tabs in firefox open with iTunes running and the stress button in Real Temp pressed.

Recent changes: location change and swapping a 1tb harddrive for a 160gb

--

Operating system: windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit

System specs: Hp dc7700 slim-line
2.0ghz core2duo
4 GB ram
160gb sata harddrive.

I realize this isn't the greatest machine, but it suits his needs for a web browser/music player. At least it should!

Location: US, Michigan

The ideas I've run down to is one of two things, either the windows install is broken, as I haven't tried a repair yet. The other option is a little weirder:
The power situation is not great where he lives to begin with. This machine is on a power strip that's massively overloaded at a glance. Two power strips, each loaded to the brim for a 52" flat screen, ps3, blu-Ray player, router, modem, external harddrive, the PC itself and a bunch of other shit. It's a mess.

I'm posting this mostly in case I've missed anything obvious or for a little extra brainstorming on the situation. I've never seen the effects of an underpowered machine before, but it seems like a solid theory at the moment. I'm simply not sure how to test this outside of moving half of it to another room and trying again. Otherwise, I'm kind of stumped. It does have a 240 watt power supply in it and most of the USB ports are clogged with things like the external drive, ipod sync cable, microsoft life cam, and a few others I can't think of at the moment. It has 6 USB ports and at least 4 were taken up.

Any help would be much obliged.

Comment: Can you try the machine at another location (bring it back home maybe) ? The power may be an issue.

Comment: You should monitor the psu output voltages. Try a tool like openhardwaremonitor can display core voltages, your mb manufacturer may have a util for monitoring psu voltages, or just use a VOM stuck in the outputs of an unused plug if available. Sometimes the bios also shows the voltages under system status section.

Comment: -1 for swearing, please do not swear, any one of any age uses this site

Comment: Can you run a SMART tool... Since it's only a hard drive change, I would vet the health. Can you also try this without the external hardware via USB.

Comment: Wouldn't crystaldiskinfo do essentially the same thing as a SMART tool?